# Cannot load assembly 'System.Web.Cors'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on calling my Web Api methods on a different port, so I need to enable `CORS`.

I've read thru the post there to get some clues: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

I've added a reference in my project to `packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors.5.2.3\lib\net45`, however when I run my project it's crashing on line:

```
 config.EnableCors(new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:1360", "*", "*"));
```

in `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs`

with the following error in Chrome browser:

```
  Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Cors, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. 
 The system cannot find the file specified.
```

```js
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\MWB-AngularJS\WorkbenchAPI\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\robertjm\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Cors, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/c1b219d5/5d7cc1d5/System.Web.Cors.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/c1b219d5/5d7cc1d5/System.Web.Cors/System.Web.Cors.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/MWB-AngularJS/WorkbenchAPI/bin/System.Web.Cors.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/MWB-AngularJS/WorkbenchAPI/bin/System.Web.Cors/System.Web.Cors.DLL.
```

Here's the code:

```js
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // enable Cors - BM:
            //config.EnableCors();
            config.EnableCors(new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:1360", "*", "*"));
            
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

and here's a section the `.csproj` file, showing the Cors reference:

```js
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.Cors, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.Cors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Help is appreciated....

Bob

Comment: I also see this post re: the same issue, but unsure how to handle the dependency references in web.confg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545211/asp-net-web-api-cannot-load-file-after-installing-cors

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. When I have installed `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` for some reason the `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` package dependency was not installed. After manual install of the package `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` the issue dissapeared.